# How I can built a QBE for Active Directory Users with activate users,email or telephonenumber and a username?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, active-directory

I work with the Active Directory. I write a method how I can get all Users from the Active Directory with a filter and list the Users in a `ArrayList` for my `DropDownList`.

The Code:

```
 private ArrayList GetReceiverList(string Domain) 
        {
            ArrayList List = new ArrayList();

            DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(Domain);

            string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=*)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*))(cn=*))"; 

            DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);

            foreach (SearchResult usr in Searcher.FindAll())
            {
                List.Add(GetLdapProperty(usr, "displayName"));
            }

            return List;
        }
```

This work and I want now do use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and for this I write a Method and this works, too. But I want do use the filter how in my first Method. How I can do this?

the code of my new method:

```
 public static ArrayList GetAllActiveDirectoryUsersByDisplayName(string dc)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc);
            UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            u.Surname = "*";
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();

            foreach (UserPrincipal usr in results)
            {
                list.Add(usr.Name);
            }

            list.Sort();

            return list;
        }
```

Update:

I want di use this filter in my new method :

```
 string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=*)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*))(cn=*))";
```

Comment: what value are you passing in for public static ArrayList GetAllActiveDirectoryUsersByDisplayName(string dc)? what does `dc` equal..?

Comment: for example (company.com) this is the domain controller

Comment: I don't get a error I want only the result with the filter of my first method... I get now all user but I want only activate users with email or phonenumber etc... see my update :P

Comment: You need to pass in the samAccount name and do the search or you have to alter the Fliter

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384378%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: yes I read this site ut there is no explain how I can search users how with this filter: (&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=*)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*))(cn=*)).  I want users with a activate account and a mail or a telephonenumber and a username, ll other user I don't want in my list

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`. It's obsolete. If you need a list of arbitrary objects, then you should use `List<object>`.

Comment: I use this arraylist for the dropdownlist bt this is not my question I want only the users with the filter in my list :P